# deleteRecord not getting called in ember-data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm making an adapter for the Web SQL storage for use in a Cordova application. So far it's going pretty well except for some reason the deleteRecord method isn't getting called at all. Here's an excerpt of my code:

```
DS.CordovaStorageAdapter = DS.Adapter.extend({
  // Other methods...
  deleteRecord: function(store, type, record) {
    console.info('Deleting!');
    var adapter = this;
    var qr = new QueryRapper({id: record.get('id')}).tableName(this.tableName(type));
    var query = qr.deleteQuery();
    console.info(query);
    function deleteSuccess(tx, results) {
      adapter.didDeleteRecord(store,type,record);
    }
    return this.db.transaction(
      function(tx) { tx.executeSql(query, [], deleteSuccess); },
      function(err) { this.dbError(query, err, type, record); }
    );
  },  
  // Support methods...
});
```

Here's my Jasmine test:

```
describe('EmberCordovaStorageAdapter', function() {
  var m;

  beforeEach(function() {
    waitForDbInit();
    runs(function() {
      m = App.TestModel.createRecord({
        string: 'String!',
        number: 1234,
        date: new Date(),
        boolean: true
      });
      m.save();
      waitForReady();
    });
  });

  // Other tests...

  it('deletes a record', function() {
    waitForReady();
    runs(function() { console.info('Deleting in test!'); m.deleteRecord(); waitForDeleted(); });
    runs(function() { expect(m.get('isDeleted')).toBe(true); });
  });

  function waitForDeleted(model) {
    model = model || m;
    waitForMessage(model, 'rootState.deleted.committed');
  }

  function waitForReady(model) {
    model = model || m;
    waitForMessage(model, 'rootState.loaded.saved');
  }

  function waitForMessage(model, msg) {
    waitsFor(function() {
      console.info(msg, model.get('stateManager.currentPath'));
      return model.get('stateManager.currentPath') == msg;
    }, 'model message: ' + msg, 1500);
  }
});
```

I'm seeing in my JS console the message "Deleting in test!" but not the message "Deleting!". The github repo can be found here: https://github.com/eltiare/ember-cordova-storage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have experience writing custom adapters, but a quick glance at your test I see your calling `deleteRecord` but I don't see a call to `commit`

In order for ember-data to actually attempt to delete the record you need to call commit. To commit the defaultTransaction you can do something like this:

```
m.get('store').commit();
```